# Set fieldset radio button value after jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, radio-button

I have a fieldset with radio buttons inside it like this:

```
<fieldset class="rating" id="ratingSystem">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" autocomplete="off" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" autocomplete="off" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" autocomplete="off" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" autocomplete="off" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" autocomplete="off" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
</fieldset>
```

And what I'm trying is to set it's default value after a jquery post is finished in done function like following:

```
$(document).on("click", ".editAction", function (event) {

   $.post("/SearchCompetitor/GetCompetitor", { id: $(this).closest('tr').find('.idRow').attr('id') })
     .done(function (data) {
     $('#TextArea1').val(data.Comment);
     $('input[name=rating]:checked').val(data.Rating).attr('checked', true);

     event.preventDefault();
     var l = document.getElementById('popap');
     l.click();
   });
});
```

The textarea value is set just fine, however I'm unable to set the value of the fieldset radio button by the value returned in data object.

The data.Rating is numerical value and can contain values from 1-5;

This is the part that's not working:

```
$('input[name=rating]:checked').val(data.Rating).attr('checked', true);
```

How can  I set the radio button value to the one that is returned in data.Rating??

Answer (score 1):

This did it:

```
$("input[name='rating'][value='"+data.Rating + "']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```